# Flutter build error for firebase cloud messaging

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Whenever i run my app i got this error.

Error Image

[image]

Pubspec.yaml

[image]

Comment: I think there could some issue in adding the analytics firebase config in your app-level build gradle when setting up Firebase.

Comment: @AdityaThakur please check https://imgur.com/LZlars7

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Just copy the original text and possibly use code format tool.

Answer (score 0):

Upadte your Gradle distribution, Android > Gradle > update your gradle